# How to use combination of AND, OR in a match query of Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my query to search about "barack obama" with AND operator:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "barack obama",
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible using match query I search this way?
"barack" AND "obama" OR "hassan" AND "rouhani"

Comment: you have to use a bool query : you can't mix both operators using the `operator` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
"query": {
        "match": {
            "title": {
                "query": "barack obama"
            }
        }
},
filter: {
    "or": [
        {
            "term": {"title":"barak obama"}
        },
        {
            "term": {"title":"hassan"}
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the reference: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-or-filter.html